# $_POST not getting data from HTML Form

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, post, phpmailer

I have a Contact Form that has the following fields: Name, Email, Website, and Message.  When the user clicks Submit, the user-inputted details must be sent via email (I used PHPMailer).

The email is sent successfully.  However, the user-inputted details were not included in the Email Message.  I have been trying to see where the problem is but I seem to not find it.

**Here is the code for my Contact Form:**

```
 <div class="right">
                        <form action="http://www.mokicruzphoto.com/testmailer.php" method="post" enctype="url-form-encoded" class="form"> 
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr> 
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px;">*Name &nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="name" style="border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3); color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);" required/></td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px;">*Email &nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><input type="email" name="email" style="border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3); color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);" required/></td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px;">Website &nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="website" style="border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3); color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);"/></td>

                                </tr>   
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px;">*Comment/Message &nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><textarea type="text" name="message" style="border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3); resize: none; width: 300px; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);" required></textarea>

                                </tr>
                                <tr></tr>
                                <tr></tr>
                                <tr></tr>
                                <tr></tr>   
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" style="border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2); background: rgba(0,0,0,0.16); width: 150px;"/></td>    
                                </tr>                                                                                                   
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </form>     
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Here is my PHP File:**

```
<?php

    require ("********************/PHPMailerAutoload.php");


    $email_add = $_POST['email'];
    $visitor = $_POST['name'];


    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "localhost"; 
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = '********************';
    $mail->Password = '********************';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail-> Port = 465;
    $mail->From =   "********************";             /*Sender*/
    $mail->FromName = "********************";               /*Sender*/
    $mail->addAddress('********************');          /*Recipient*/
    $mail->addReplyTo('********************');
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Test Email';
    $mail->Body    = 'Hi Iam using PHPMailer library to sent SMTP mail from localhost. This is a test email by JC Pineda';
    if(!$mail->send()) {
       echo 'Message could not be sent.';
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       exit;
    }
    echo 'Message has been sent';

    ?>
```

**If it helps, here is my HTACCESS as well:**

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have missed attribute for both you comment and website.

```
<td><input name="theNameYouNeed"></td>
```

For instance you comment would need

```
<td><input name="comment"></td>
```

Also you need to in addition too

```
$email_add = $_POST['email'];
$visitor = $_POST['name'];
```

Have to add a `$_POST` for the other forms too.
Also you have not echo or printed them anywhere for them to show up.

Edit: The issue for anyone who wants the answer in full was that he was using the  element instead of the input element. The `<textarea>` tag will not created a valid `name` attribute used for php data.

Comment: I already put the name attribute on the Website and Message fields.  I also posted them in my php file but it still won't work

Comment: Wow, @Armand, your suggestion regarding the <input> tag is correct.  I simply changed the <textarea> tag to <input>.  It's now working. Thank you very much

Comment: @Jpineds Nice, sometimes it is the simple things that drive us crazy.

Comment: Yes. Haha. However, why is the <textarea> tag not postable?

Comment: Textarea is something that holds text... thats it. Input is something that holds a user input. POST is a user input type thing (yes I said thing). There we need to use input.

Comment: Actually, <textarea> *is* an type of input field and should work with your form. the difference between <textarea> and a regular <input> tag is that the textarea shows multiple lines of text. (for example: this very comment box is a textarea)

Answer (score 2):

All form elements that you'd like to retrieve server-side must have a `name` attribute set. You seem to be missing this attribute for the **website** and **comment** input fields.

Example HTML changes:

```
<tr>
    <td style="font-size: 12px;">Website &nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="website" style="border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3); color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);"/></td>
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td style="font-size: 12px;">*Comment/Message &nbsp;</td>
    <td><textarea type="text" name="message" style="border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3); resize: none; width: 300px; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);" required></textarea>
</tr>
```

Then retrieve it server-side:

```
$website = $_POST['website'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

Comment: hi @hberg, I tried your solution but it still won't work

Comment: @Jpineds, try adding `id="contactForm"` to your `<form>` tag and then add `form="contactForm"` to the `<textarea>` tag. This assigns the form an id and then associates the textarea with that form. But like hberg said, you need to set a unique name attribute for every input source.

Answer (score 1):

Remove enctype="text/plain" because the encoding type should be the default, which is 'url-form-encoded'.

Then you may debug it further by looking at the raw POST data:

```
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
```

or simply

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: i tried changing the encoding type, but it still won't work.  The print_r($_POST) returned this: Array ( ) 1

Comment: Can you create a simple php file, and just have print_r($_POST)? I'd like to rule out any interference there might be.

Comment: it still returned the same string: Array ( ) 1

Comment: At this point it's almost safe to conclude that something's off with your server/PHP run-time setup.

Comment: I am using a Godaddy hosting.  What could be the problem?

Comment: I just tested your script by posting to testmailer.php. It works. You can't simply load that page alone and expect $_POST to show. You have to fill out the form data and click on the submit button. Otherwise $_POST will always be empty.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to hberg's answer, you need to incorporate your field variables into the building of your `$mail->Body` property.  Right now you have a simple string assigned to `$mail->Body` that does not incorporate the field variables at all.

For example, try this:

```
$mail->Body = "Submitted Email: $email_add , Name: $visitor";
```

Note that you must use double quotes if you actually build the string with variables within. I'd prefer to use the `printf()` function to build such a string but the above example should at least see if your POST variables are actually working.

Comment: what do you mean by incorporating the field variables into the Body? Does this mean that all field variables must be included in the Body?